# Multilabel grid search in ScikitLearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to scikit-learn and I want to do find the best parameters for multi-label classification problem with scikit-learn GridSearch. I cannot get it working and I am pretty sure there is something wrong with labelling.

My code looks like this:

```
X, Y = load_svmlight_file( TRAIN_FILE, dtype=np.float64, multilabel=True )

clf_pipeline = OneVsRestClassifier(
            Pipeline([('pca', RandomizedPCA()),
                      ('clf', SVC())
                      ]))
#grid search parameters
c_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 9)
gamma_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-5, 4)
n_components_range = (10, 100, 200)
degree_range = (1, 2, 3, 4)

#grid search
param_grid = dict(estimator__clf__gamma=gamma_range,
              estimator__clf__c=c_range,
              estimator__clf__degree=degree_range,
              estimator__pca__n_components=n_components_range)

grid = GridSearchCV(clf_pipeline, param_grid, verbose=2)
grid.fit(X, Y)
```

The occurs in the line "grid.fit(X,Y)".
Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 597, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 359, in _fit
    cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1361, in _check_cv
    cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv, indices=needs_indices)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 429, in __init__
    label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I use scikit-learn 0.15.

Edit1. The code works perfectly well in Linux, but not on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: It's most likely an issue with your data. You may want to check the data file and revisit the loading

Comment: The data is loaded through standard procedure load_svmlight_file, where the data itself is just tdf-idf vectors. Works OK for just classifying, but not GridSearch

Comment: Your code looks very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225882/gridsearch-for-multilabel-onevsrestclassifier Have you looked at that question?

Comment: I doubt that it really works on Linux. [Multi-label cross-validation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26018543/166749) isn't implemented.